# Does the 4-gem piece in Columns 3 actually exist?

Tags: sega-genesis, columns-3

Back on ye olde Genesis, the game Columns 3 has a peculiar image on the backside of its box:

[image: Huh.]

This screenshot (located on the top right of the box) depicts both players having pieces that have extra halves on the top and bottom.

Normally I would dismiss this as just a bizarre probably-capture-artifacting thing, but my memory assures me that it absolutely is possible and has occurred once before, and none of the other images on the box have any image quality issues.

So... I'm asking if anybody has any definitive proof either way. The image below is pretty low-resolution, but I don't think I have my box around to scan any more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The extra blocks you are seeing are just artifacts from the previous frame of the game. Caused by either the TV or camera used.

I am sure of this because the UI for the next piece doesn't have enough room for 4 blocks.

Looking through some game guides shows no mention of 4 blocks either.